# Virtual host with ProxyPassReverse and preserve sub link

Tags: virtualhost, host

I'm hosting a web site using Apache and i'd like to create a virtual host like freepbx like mydomain.com/freepbx.  freepbx runs on port 7000, and when I create the virtual host it automatically redirects, when i go in a sub link, to my main site.  the webserver run on a machine 192.168.1.110. frepbx run on a 192.168.1.109:7000. Is there a way to create a system where I can substitute the links?  Right now I'm using:

```
   ProxyRequests Off
       ProxyPreserveHost On
 <Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /freepbx/ http://192.168.1.109:7000
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://192.168.1.109:7000 /freepbx
ProxyPassReverse /freepbx/ http://192.168.1.109:7000
<Location />
Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
  </Location>
```

but this doesn't work.
images of secondary website is not visible and so on.

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If your web application on port 7000 does not explicitly support reverse proxy, then you may be better using same URIs on both proxy and actual app. In your case / on proxy should be mapped to / on 192.168.1.109:7000. You can use virtual hosts to have separate domain roots.

I can also see you're missing trailing slashes in destination URLs, not sure if it can be a problem here but worth checking.

Comment: ok but is not the unique case where proxyreverese not work. i have other website in my intranet and also this not work or better when im access website with sub links. look if is possible this http://raspmattly.dyndns.org/nas/ in this case the website has lost image and is not complete

Comment: @MatteoLioi Same applies to other sites. I see your edits, but still without fixing the trailing slash issue.